# Line of text next to the first line in a select box?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a simple way to add a styled line of small text next to the first line in a select box?

For example:

[image: box]

I'm using code like the following:

```
<select name="textarea" size="10" multiple="multiple" id="textarea">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something else</option>
  <option>another thing</option>
  </select>
```

The text would only ever need to be displayed next to what ever data was on the first line. If you could help that would be brilliant!

Comment: Would "first line" ever be different from "first option"?

Comment: Yes it would as I am already using a script which moves selected options to the top of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`option` elements do not allow nesting of other html element, so you wouldn't be able to change the style of part of the string.  You can, of course, use a javascript "fancy drop-down"-type script that will create a pseudo-select element that allows you to go nuts with the styles.  But with a plain old `select` tag, no dice.

Comment: is there a way to at least change the colour of the first line do you know via CSS?

Comment: You can always add inline CSS or a class to one or more OPTION tags as a whole.  Check out this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bGpdb/  From there, you might be able to use some of the CSS3 pseudo-selectors like `first-letter`, but those aren't necessarily cross-browser, and they might not fit your needs anyway since you can't get right in there with specific styles.